# How can I extract a zip archive that contains a forbidden file name on Windows using Python?

Tags: python, windows, zip

I've been trying to write a Python program to assist with installing Minecraft mods. This requires extracting an obfuscated JAR file and adding some new classes. However, one of the obfuscated files is called `aux.class`. Any file named `aux`, no matter what extension, is forbidden on Windows due to it being a DOS device name. I need to figure out some way to extract this file and then rearchive it while keeping Windows happy. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't *have* to write the file, or extract it. you can use

```
toolzip = zipfile.ZipFile(myzipfile,  'r')
names = toolzip.namelist()
for n in names:
    data = toolzip.read(n)
    # do something with data
```

including writing the data back to another zip.

Comment: Why are you using the undocumented lower-level `_zipfile` module (which is only there in early CPython 2.x, not other implementations, or 3.x, or even 2.6) instead of [`zipfile`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile)?

Comment: @Nathan2055: It looks like it. But why not read the docs and/or try it and see?

Comment: actually, sorry.... borrowed that from code that renames globals with _ (because they are used interactively a lot, so it cleans up the interactive namespace). it was actually the standard `zipfile` module, not the low-level one. just fixed to point to the correct one.